# Measuring phase difference - LTSPice simulation problem

Tags: simulation, flipflop, ltspice, ultrasound, phase

I'm trying to detect the phase difference between two signals (voltage and current) given from the same source (an ultrasound generator) which works at 20kHz approximately.

I found a circuit that is supposed to do that, but when I do the simulation with LTSpice I think that I'm doing it wrong because it does not works as it's told in the page. I think that the D-Flip Flop is not working as expected.

I "test it" using different phases for one of the signals and it gives me very different results in the different simulations.

Can anyone look at the file and  give me some help so I can do the simulation correctly?

I attach the LTSpice file:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=1

Image obtained from: www.next.gr/meter-counter/meters/measuring-phase-difference-l12144.html

[image: image obtained from: www.next.gr/meter-counter/meters/measuring-phase-difference-l12144.html]

Comment: Looks good to me (D F/F output is high when A leads B, low when B leads A). In what way is it not working 'as expected'?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. 
I think it's not working as the page which I obtain the photo says it works (www.next.gr/meter-counter/meters/measuring-phase-difference-l12144.html).
I should get different dc values if I get different phase shifts, or not?

Comment: Your LtSpice file does not simulate the entire circuit.

Comment: Oh, DB didn't synchronize the file. Sorry. Here is the complete circuit
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D flip-flop *is* working as expected, but your simulation has other issues:-

1. the LT1716 comparator is much slower than the uA710 (~3us switching time vs 20ns). At 20kHz this slow switching causes noticeable pulse timing distortion. To improve accuracy you need to lower the input frequency (to eg. 2kHz).
2. Your digital logic blocks are set at their default logic levels of 0-1V (compared to ~0-3.5V for TTL) so the output amplitude will be lower than in the original circuit.

Note that the uA710 has TTL compatible outputs, but with a negative supply the LT1716 will pull *below* ground (which is *not* compatible with most digital logic families). It only works in LTspice because the simulated logic has no input voltage restrictions.

Other issues are shared with the original circuit:-

3. No resistor between the flop-flop output and 2N2369 Base. In a real circuit this would probably stress the flip-flop and increase saturation voltage of the transistor.
4. The 2N2369 has a fairly high saturation voltage which affects the output when it is turned on. It should be replaced with a low saturation type such as FTZ849.
5. When the transistor turns on it reconfigures the associated op amp from inverting to non-inverting mode, but also lowers the impedance at point E which reduces the signal voltage. This can be fixed by inserting a unity gain buffer amp between the output of the low pass filter and the 2x 15k resistors.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the observations, I'm doing the changes right now!
I don't understand how to make the digital blocks to have a range from 0v to 3.5v. Can you enlight me?

Comment: Right-click on the component to edit its attributes, double-click in the value column of the "Value" attribute and enter "Vhigh=3.5".

Comment: Hi! I changed the circuit following your recomendations (except the transistor because the soft doesn't have it) and change the flip-flop source for a positive one instead the -5v. 
I think that the circuit isn't working as the web tolds it works. Can you look it please? Thank very very much for your help

Comment: link to your latest version?

Comment: It's the same, I uploaded the DB file!
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=1

Comment: F/F Preset and Clear must be connected to Ground, not +5V. Your digital output voltage is larger so the signal is also larger and overloads U6 above about +-120º. So reduce the gain of U6, or remove it and take the output directly from U5.  If you don't have FTZ849 then try 2N3904.

Comment: It's still working in range of milivolts between the different phase values that I tested. I think that it doesn't have good resolution.
Is there a way generate more (voltage) difference and improve the resolution?

Comment: After grounding preset/clear and changing R9 to 1k I got 4.79V @ -179º to -4.77V @ 179º, which is 27mV per degree. To get greater sensitivity you must increase the gain, but then the final op amp will saturate at high angles unless you also increase the supply voltages. If you are only interested in a small range of angles then you can increase the gain and add a bias voltage to get inside the range. For example with R9 = 47k and -2.5V on the bottom end of R8 I got 4.78V @ 45º to -4.69V at 155º, which is 86mV per degree.

Comment: Note that the low pass filter (R3/R4/C1/C2) has a very long settling time, so you may need to simulate for 2 seconds or more to get an accurate result. To speed up the simulation I reduced C1 and C2 to 0.0022uF and stop time to 20ms.

Comment: Oh, at first sight it works awesome! Thank you very much. I have a last question if you don't mind. What is the difference in the implementation of using the values of capacitors that you told (0.0022uf) me or using the original values (0.22 uf)?

Comment: Small caps charge quicker so the voltage settles faster. If you wait long enough the result is the same with larger caps. However on my PC simulating that takes several minutes! Small caps work well at 20kHz, but at lower frequencies larger caps are needed to reduce ripple.